# Does RDBMS provides result caching?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, caching, memcached, rdbms

Does RDBMs(SQLServer and oracle) provides feature to cache query results something like memcaches/redis/ehcache etc ? If yes is it by default or need configuration ?

I believe no reading this [Memcached vs SQL Server cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084789/memcached-vs-sql-server-cache) but here is counter answer

Comment: [Oracle - Tuning the Result Cache](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA616)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does provide a results cache. It's not enabled by default; you have to configure how much memory is assigned to it.